# Using comma as decimal separator

Tags: c#, double

From the Client the user inserts a double number, and the only rule must be that if it has the 'dot' it has to be converted in comma. Problem it is that when I pass the number with the comma as separator to the controller through AJAX, the parameter double in controller can't read the value and it crashes. This is the reason I had to put parameter string to the controller so it can read the value.

```
var pesoArticolo = $("#editPesoArticoloTextBox").val();
pesoArticolo = pesoArticolo.replace(".", ",");
```

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ProcessEditPesoArticolo(int idArticolo, string pesoArticolo)
{           
  var pesoArticoloDouble = double.Parse(pesoArticolo, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Problem in the controller it is that I cannot find any method that convert the separator to the 'comma'. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture has also the problem that if the number is 0,067 it removes all the leading zero and become 67.

Any solution to that? I need to use the comma as separator because it has to be saved into a database (float field) that is also read by another software which uses comma as separator.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a culture that uses a comma as the decimal separator (example - "DE-de" for Germany)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ProcessEditPesoArticolo(int idArticolo, string pesoArticolo)
{           
  // replace DE-de with your own culture
  var pesoArticoloDouble = double.Parse(pesoArticolo, new CultureInfo("DE-de"));
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cuTggE

Comment: I tried this culture info, but it still isn't working and inserting the dot instead comma :<

Comment: I've added a link to a .NET fiddle to demonstrate some usages. How did you try it in your code?

Comment: I added the same code as your, except the output writeline because I see the value through debug in Visual Studio, and it remains with the dot instead than comma.
"
            var culture = new CultureInfo("DE-de");
            var pesoArticoloDouble = double.Parse("1,23", culture);
"

Comment: Visual Studio will display it in your computer's culture. Now that you have successfully parsed a string of "1,23" into a valid double, you can do with it what you want. While it is a double in your code, you can use it as a number. You really only need to treat it with a culture when you parse it and display it to the user. What are you trying to achieve next?

Comment: Important it is that it saves the number with the comma into the database when I am going to save the number

Comment: it doesn't save the double into the table as I thought, it reads the dot instead comma still